# SSRS taking a long time to refresh dataset when using a stored procedure as a 'Query Type'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using a parameterised stored procedure to retrieve data for a SSRS report. When I create a new shared dataset for the report, it takes a significant amount of time to populate the fields and parameters.

Am I right in thinking that the dataset is attempting to retrieve from the stored procedure in an attempt to populate its fields and parameter definitions?

Is there a way to stop it trying to retrieve my entire database 1.8 million (non parameterised) rows just to populate the fields and parameter definitions?

Comment: You could add the parameters and fields manually to the definition of the dataset; then SSRS wouldn't attempt to work out what they are by sending a query to the database to get a description of the dataset. Though if your query really is that slow, perhaps you should be looking at performance tuning it.

Comment: _Am I right_ Yes, you are. You can temporarily add a filter like "where 1 = 0" for the purpose of creating and then remove it.

Comment: Each report has its own SP to retrieve the data, however some of those use a nested, centralised SP which has about 20 parameters and trawls the whole database. We use a central retrieval SP to maintain data continuity across multiple reports and embedded charts.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL of the stored procedure has been modified to return no records if ALL the parameters are NULL.
Whilst this is not ideal it is the only way to work with stored procedures (used in SSRS) for potentially large data retrievals.